# How to access a cucumber CONSTANT in cucumber env.rb from a page object (siteprism) ruby class?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, constants, pageobjects, site-prism

I'm defining a CONSTANT in my env.rb file in cucumber as:

```
CONFIG = YAML::load_file("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../configs/config.yaml")
```

Then I want to access values from that 'config.yaml' file, like `CONFIG['url']`.

The problem I'm having is that I've got a page object siteprism class and I don't know how to access it?

```
class MyPage < SitePrism::Page
  set_url CONFIG['url']
...
```

it's failing with:

```
uninitialized constant MyPage::CONFIG (NameError)
```

I want to access the CONFIG constant that was defined in my env.rb file though, not a constant from MyPage. Do you guys know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `::`, like `::CONFIG['url']`.

Notice that given that you have `"YAML::load_file("` for `CONFIG`, the value of this expression would be `nil`.

Comment: sorry, the quotes were a typo. Edited. 

When I tried ::CONFIG['url'] inside the MyPage class I got:
`uninitialized constant CONFIG
Did you mean?  RbConfig (NameError)`

Comment: Is the env.rb file somehow loaded?

Comment: I think the problem is something specific to SitePrism, although I'm not sure what. That gem has a method called `set_url`, so if I try to use CONFIG there it doesn't work and fails with the errors above. 
However, if I try to use CONFIG in that class but inside a new method that I create there it works fine. I tried to workaround the issue by using `set_url(new_method_to_retrieve_CONFIG)`, but that didn't work either. Not sure if there's any workaround. For now, I'm just duplicating the 'url' in my config file and in the `set_url "http://url"` command...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your load order is correct.
Use toplevel namespace as advised.
Better logic would be to delegate this to a Helper Module, include this helper module in your class. Then call the helper Module method

```
class MyKlass
  include MyHelper

  set_url helper_method[:key]
end

module MyHelper
  def helper_method
    {
      key: 'http://www.google.com/'
    }
  end
end
```

If anyone else believes that set_url isn't working. Feel free to raise an issue on the SitePrism repo: https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism/issues, or ask here if easier